# make a default view for google crawler when loading content with ajax

Tags: ajax, seo, web-crawler, blogs

I am working on a blog that loads **all posts with ajax** with a nice effect.

The problem is that **google is not reading** anything.

I am working in a **script that loads all content directly** if the browser does not support ajax, and **for crawlers**.

I want to know if Google considers that this is **Black hat SEO**, or if it's the correct solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool for that at Google Webmaster Tools (Search Console). It is called "Fetch and Render". Log in to your Webmaster Tools find the tool in the crawl section, insert the URLs page then use it and Google will answer your question about how the bot view vs the human view. If you need help finding the tool or setting Webmaster Tools, ask me.

Comment: If you don't have any more questions and i have answered your question you can check it for "answered" and close the topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the content in your  tag exactly matches what users would see, then that's not black hat

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid to make SEO going worse when trying to improve it!

Comment: You're welcome :) Use the tool that @George Stefas has suggested to review which elements of the page are visible to Googlebot and compare to the regular view that human users will see. So long as the main content matches (irrespective of formatting), you should be OK.